# How to build a c++ program in Eclipse which uses SDL2

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, sdl-2

I have made a program in C++ with Eclipse. If I build it and run it on my machine, it works fine. But if I send it to someone who doesn't have the SDL framework, it doesn't work. My machine and the other machine which doesn't work with it is a mac. What do I need to change to build my program?

The build console in Eclipse just says this:

```
00:14:23 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project     Salsa Kit ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/main.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.o" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/main.cpp

Building target: Salsa Kit.app
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -L/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework -L/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework -framework SDL2 -framework Cocoa -framework          SDL2_image -o "Salsa Kit.app"  ./src/engine/SE.o ./src/engine/SE_Audio.o ./src/engine/SE_Graphics.o ./src/engine/SE_Input.o  ./src/main.o   
Finished building target: Salsa Kit.app


00:14:26 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 3s.139ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the required runtime libraries (such as SDL, the Visual Studio redistributables, etc, anything you use) with your application.

Usually you'd add the required libraries to the applications installer/package - which you also need to build.

For Windows that would usually be a MSI file. For Linux, a RPM or DEB package is common.

Comment: Jesper Juhi How would you include the libraries?

Comment: @Luke Pasfield : You'd add code to your build system to build an installer/package. In that package you would add the required binary files (libraries) along with instructions to copy them to appropriate locations on the target system when the application is installed.

Comment: There was an easier way I've heard of where you can just do something with linking the libraries. I asked this question on cplusplus.com and someone gave me this answer: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/244070/ the 4th comment. I couldn't find any way to link it.

Comment: @Luke In *some* cases you can statically link all libraries and then the executable will be self contained. That requires that your compiler supports static linking of its runtime libraries and that all other libraries you use also support static linking. Not always possible, but if it is and that's what you want, then go for it. Btw; building an installer is not *hard* - a days work (or two).